# Magento 2 - How to call a custom phtml file in another phtml file, xml layout, static block and cms page?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am creating a magento 2 theme. I just want to know how can I add .phtml file in *`xml layout, static block, cms page`* or in another *`.phtml`* file. Thank You.

Answer (score 72):

**For improving documentation/answer**

Custom file path

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml
```

calling in `xml layout` file

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"/>
```

Calling in `blocks and cms pages`

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}
```

Calling in any `phtml` file

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml')) ?>
```

OR, as before

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Calling in blocks and cms pages - method doesn't working... It generates 500 internal server error. (using 2.0.5 version). do you have any idea?

Comment: this answer is amazing.  So much info in one place, that is basically impossible to find in the Magento documentation.

Comment: Thanks @MilanChandro ! +1 But I have a question. How do I call newsletter phtml using above technique. However the newsletter form is appearing fine but not working???

Answer (score 6):

General convention is 
`<VendorName_ModuleName>::relative/path/to/phtml/in/templates/`

**Examples:**

- in xml layout
  [`<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="default_home_page" template="Magento_Cms::default/home.phtml"/>`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml#L21)
- in phtml
  [`<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_defaultindex.xml#L11)

Answer (score 1):

**Your custom file path**

```
app/code/{vendor_name}/{module_name}/view/frontend/templates/custom.phtml
```

**calling in phtml file into cms block and pages**:-

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"}}
```

OR

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\your_file_name" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"}}
```

**calling in xml layout file:-**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml">
```

**calling in another phtml file:-**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::custom.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call phtml template file from within another phtml template file:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::test.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

test.phtml will be located in app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/templates